# Why the owner of a database can't alter the tables of this database that are owned by other owners?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, owner

For now I don't understand why this access rights segregation exist.
Is it implemented for some security reasons? Or can it be needed by some use cases I can't imagine right now?

Knowing almost nothing about the reasons behind concrete PostgreSQL design I wonder why prevent a database owner from altering those tables of the database owned that are owned by other owners.

Here's what [the official documentation on altering tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-altertable.html) says regarding who can alter tables of a database:

> You must own the table to use ALTER TABLE.

Of course I don't argue the design or the documentation. I'm just wondering why it can be needed to limit a database owner that way?

Answer (score 0):

It is a security consideration. One way to get around it is to have all objects created by specific user(s) have [default rights](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html).

In my opinion you should limit what user(s) can do DDL in a database for a number of reasons. Primarily for security and controlling who/what user can do DDLs. For a small company / personal setup may not matter, but the second you have multiple people working on a DB can get pretty chaotic if you don't control it.